# C sharp delimiter

Tags: c#-3.0

In a given sentence i want to split into 10 character string.  The last word should not be incomplete in the string. Splitting should be done based on  space or `,` or `.`

For example:
 `this is ram.he works at mcity.`

now the substring of 10 chars is,
`this is ra.`
but the output should be,
`this is.`
Last word should not be incomplete

Comment: How do you know if the last word is incomplete?  You can look up the regular expression for the three delimiters, and use that, but the incompleteness requirement needs more information.

Comment: What should happen if the first word is longer than 10 characters?

Comment: You said string spliting should be based on SPACE* , or .  You didn't split on space?

Comment: Why are you ignoring question marks, semi-colons and other punctuation? What if the input is "12345678..."? Should the output be "12345678.." truncating the ellipsis part way through? I really would like to see some more examples of how this should work, especially how edge cases should be handled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression that checks that the character after the match is not a word character:

```
string input = "this is ram.he";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^.{0,10}(?!\w)");
string result;
if (match.Success)
{
    result = match.Value;
}
else
{
    result = string.Empty;
}
```

Result:

```
this is
```

---

An alternative approach is to build the string up token by token until adding another token would exceed the character limit:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"\w+|\W+"))
{
    if (sb.Length + match.Value.Length > 10) { break; }
    sb.Append(match.Value);
}
string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 Didn't even think about using regular expressions. Much better!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the sort of thing you were looking for.  Note that this could be done a lot cleaner, but should get you started ... (may want to use StringBuilder instead of String).

```
    char[] delimiterChars = { ',', '.',' ' };
    string s = "this is ram.he works at mcity.";

    string step1 = s.Substring(0, 10);   // Get first 10 chars

    string[] step2a = step1.Split(delimiterChars);    // Get words
    string[] step2b = s.Split(delimiterChars);        // Get words

    string sFinal = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < step2a.Count()-1; i++)     // copy count-1 words
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            sFinal = step2a[i];
        }
        else
        {
            sFinal = sFinal + " " + step2a[i];
        }
    }

    // Check if last word is a complete word.

    if (step2a[step2a.Count() - 1] == step2b[step2a.Count() - 1])
    {
        sFinal = sFinal + " " + step2b[step2a.Count() - 1] + ".";
    }
    else
    {
        sFinal = sFinal + ".";
    }
```